# How to execute byte arrays of a EXE or DLL file into memory

Tags: arrays, powershell, portable-executable

Hello i want to learn memory system and injecting executables into memory.

I made this:

```
$ByteArray = (Invoke-WebRequest "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1033846522636410930/1033857198088011807/s.exe").Content

# Encode base64 string to byte array
$Base64String = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($ByteArray);
$InputString = $Base64String

# Decode base64 string to byte array
$PEBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($InputString)
 
execution
{

  # I dont know how to execute that decoded byte array "$PEBytes"

}
```

it works good but it doesn't executes target file and i don't know this part.

How i can execute byte array ($PEBytes)?

NOT: btw exe file in link is safe it just writes a empty text file to my desktop file you can test code with another link.

Comment: As an aside: If  a byte array is returned from the web-service call, why don't you use it directly instead of converting it to Base64 first and the converting it back to a byte array?

Comment: Is the `.exe` file a _native_ (PE) executable, as your variable name suggests, or is it a .NET executable?

Comment: Hello firstly thanks for reply. Yes its good idea but im new to powershell i will be happy if you show me how :D

Comment: @mklement0 No i made it with python, not .NET does it matter???

Comment: What Python feature, module, ... did you use to create an `.exe` file? Does it all have to be done _in memory_? You can use `-OutFile` with [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) to write to a _file_, and then execute that.

Comment: It matters in that .NET-based executables are also .NET _assemblies_, and there are .NET APIs to load assemblies from byte arrays.

Comment: i used this code in python: `f= open("guru99.txt","w+")` with no module and used pyinstaller to convert it exe. Yes i can use `-OutFile` and execute it, i know how to do it but i want execute this from memory to protect my source / project file.

Comment: thats no problem i just make it for testing does it creates txt file or not, I can make a another exe file in c# .Net i just want learn system

Comment: I've added the  [tag:pe] tag, which may help attract subject-matter experts. Pragmatically speaking: you can download to a _temporary_ file, execute and _await its termination_, then delete the file. This isn't perfect protection, but neither is in-memory execution.